# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

Tags: c#

хочу настроить восстановление работы приложения с той точки, с которой была закончена работа приложения системой, но возникает ошибка ,  У меня двухстраничное приложение , если на главное странице воспроизводить остановку приложения системой  то все нормально , но со второй страницей ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

делаю по обучающему видео , в их примере все нормально, в моем по аналогии нет https://mva.microsoft.com/ru/training-courses/-windows-10-15867?l=wg7YwPv7B_205192797
17:11 время

часть кода, где возникает ошибка

```
private void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
        {
            var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
            //TODO: Сохранить состояние приложения и остановить все фоновые операции
            Frame frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
            *ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["NavigationState"] = frame.GetNavigationState();*
            deferral.Complete();
        }
```

Comment: а что в просмотре сведений?

Comment: !https://pp.userapi.com/c841025/v841025104/af21/VSbwRjwvvKc.jpg

Answer (score 0):

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/ad753362-0d52-42b3-8917-b2897033ba49/getnavigationstate-doesnt-support-serialization-of-a-parameter-type-which-was-passed-to?forum=winappswithcsharp&forum=winappswithcsharp

Чтобы включить сериализацию состояния кадра с помощью [GetNavigationState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame.getnavigationstate.aspx), вы должны передать только базовые типы для этого метода, такие как строковые, char, числовые и GUID-типы. Если вы передаете объект в качестве параметра, запись в стеке навигации фрейма содержит ссылку на объект до тех пор, пока кадр не будет выпущен или эта запись не будет выпущена при новой навигации, которая будет расходиться со стеком. В общем, мы препятствуем передаче не-базового типа в качестве параметра для навигации, потому что он не может быть сериализован, когда приложение приостановлено, и может потреблять больше памяти, потому что ссылка хранится в стеке навигации фрейма, чтобы позволить приложению идти Вперед и назад.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23896488/getnavigationstate-doesnt-support-serialization-of-a-parameter-type-which-was-p